# Docker container after restart:- Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-container

I have created a docker container with the below command.

```
docker run -it -d --privileged=true Debian-base init
```

After restart this container when I tried to start any service using systemctl or service or /etc/init.d/ got below error message.

```
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

Comment: To a first approximation, `systemctl`, `service`, and init scripts don't work in Docker at all.  You should just run the program you want to run, as a foreground process, as the main process in a container.

Comment: This docker image `https://hub.docker.com/r/jrei/systemd-debian` works for me.